# Intel MAX 10 DDR output

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

I want to output a clock signal via a DDR register. The target FPGA is an Intel MAX 10 (10M16DAU324I7G) FPGA. I instantiate an ALTDDIO_OUT component as shown in the code below. However, the output Pin stays permanently low. Clock is running, Pin in R15.
Can anyone provide a hint what my problem could be?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

library altera_mf;
use altera_mf.altera_mf_components.all;

entity ddr_test
    port(
        clk_in  : in  std_logic;        
        clk_out : out std_logic
    );
end entity ddr_test;

architecture rtl of ddr_test is
    signal s_clk : std_logic;
begin
    s_clk <= clk_in; --omitted the global clock network for simplicity

    i_ODDR : component ALTDDIO_OUT
        generic map(
            width => 1
        )
        port(
            datain_h   => "1",
            datain_l   => "0",
            outclock   => s_clk,
            dataout(0) => clk_out
        );
end architecture rtl;
```

Comment: How is `clk_out` connected with the pin you are observing?

Comment: `clk_out` is connected to an Xilinx MPSoC. I have changed the pin to connect to an LED, no change in behavior. `s_clk` is an internal clock signal on a global clock network.

Comment: So you are looking at an LED which is turned on and off several thousand or million times per second?

Comment: Yes, should be dimmed, but is constantly off.

Comment: How about using an oscilloscope? I doubt you will be able to see anything with the LED.

Comment: The signal does not reach to MPSoC either. Hardware connection is fine.

Comment: But again, how did you specify that the signal `clk_out` is connected to the output pin of the FPGA? How do you generate the `s_clk` signal? Please show a [mre].

Comment: I think what the other comments are suggesting is you bypass the DDR register for now and connect clkin directly to clkout, to verify the rest of the environment (I/O pin constraint files etc). If you CAN see clkout, try the DDR reg. If you can't, debug the rest of the environment first; for example, if you must use a LED, make clkin 1 Hz or so, or connect it to a push button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Direct instantiation of the ALTDDIO_OUT primitive does not seem to work reliably on the chosen FPGA and/or tool chain (MAX 10, Quartus Prime 18.1).
The solution is to generate an IP core with the MegaWizard GPIO Lite Intel FPGA IP using a DDR register output.

Comment: But why does ALTDDIO_OUT not work reliably?

Comment: @quantum231 That's a very good question. The tool chain did not issue any warning and the routed design looked fine in ChipPlanner. However, the output was constant 0.

Comment: Please do submit a service request to Intel for them to look into this problem